# Html.RadioButtonFor Radio Buttons aren't rendering in Safari nor Chrome

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, google-chrome, safari

Yikes!  My radio buttons render in every browser except Safari and Google Chrome.

Using ASP.NET MVC 4, I wrote this in one of my views:

```
    <!-- model property1 -->
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.property1)
        <div class="form-control">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.property1, true)
            @Html.Label("Yes")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.property1, false)
            @Html.Label("No")
        </div>
    </div>
```

But it ended up looking like this on the page:

[image: all of my buttons ran away]

So I tried giving both of the radio buttons unique IDs to see if it fixed the problem:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.property1, true, new {@id = "property1_true"})
@Html.Label("Yes")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.property1, false, new {@id = "property1_false"}))
@Html.Label("No")
```

It didn't. In Google Chrome, the HTML looks like this:

```
<!-- model property1 -->
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="property1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?</label>
    <div class="form-control">
        <input id="property1_true" name="property1" type="radio" value="True" />
        <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
        <input id="property1_false" name="property1" type="radio" value="False" />
        <label for="No">No</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm running Safari 5.1.7 for Windows, and Chrome 37.0.

Comment: in the console on those browsers are you seeing any errors?  can you also post the html that is rendered by those browsers?

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the response.  I added the HTML rendered by Chrome.  I believe Safari renders it the same way, but I would be willing to double-check if needed.  As for console errors, I get errors related to jQuery-migrate: `JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.event.handle is undocumented and deprecated`, etc.  Nothing else. I don't believe the errors are related to this problem.

Comment: interesting that the tags are there and correct but they don't show.  out of curiosity, if you put the rendered code into your view instead of the helper, does it then render correctly?

Comment: @Matt I know, right?  But no, the radio buttons still don't show when I copy and paste the rendered HTML into my view.

Comment: Unfortunately I am at a loss at this point.  My only suggestion would be to try to remove that error.  I have had weird things happen on my views in the past when I had an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much sleuthing, the solution was painfully easy.  I didn't inspect the CSS carefully enough:

```
input:not([type='checkbox']) {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

So it's not a really a browser compatibility issue, nor an encoding issue, nor an malformed HTML issue (etc etc etc).